# Featured image not appearing

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type, the featured image works in our blog post type however in our ebooks page, it shows the placeholder instead of the featured image whats weird is the code shows it calls the featured url just like it does with the blog page. and it is pulling the right link but not overriding the placeholder image.

Comment: can you please share a code here so I can check it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.